# Draw a parabola y^2=x using the mid point algorithm?

Tags: graphics

i need to how parabola is drawn using midpoint algorithm. i got how to obtain the circle and line and also ellipse but couldn't get proper method for parabola. can anyone help me out for doing it from beginning to end.

Comment: Show us what code you've written so far, and let us know what tools/language you are using.

Comment: You can refer to this [explanation](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-write-a-C-program-to-draw-a-parabola-using-the-midpoint-algorithm), this would give you some heads up.